# How to use Javascript Function in all Tags of html with Shuffle and random text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shuffle

please help me to fixed this problem.
I want to add javascript in tag html but its only work 1 times, why can't 2 or more times?

This is my code :
**JS**

```
// Array of words 
var words = ["Andre", "Anne", "Billy", "Clark","David", "Edward", "Gee", "Jasper", "Kelvin", "Steven", "Tom", "Willy"]; 
// Function that executes every 5000 milliseconds 
var t = setInterval(function() { 
// Random number generator 
var randomNumber = Math.round( Math.random() * (words.length-1) ); 
// Change the word in the span for a random one in the array of words 
$('#word').html( words[ randomNumber ] ); 
}, 5000); 
document.getElementById("word").innerHTML;
```

**CSS**

```
#word {
align-content: center;
display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../word.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="text" id="word">Franco</p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="text" id="word">Henry</p>//in this class the javascript doesn't work
</div>
</body>
```

You can also check my website, what's wrong with my coding.
https://172.96.190.173/rtpsosbobet/
Thankyou

Comment: In HTML, IDs are unique. Only one of your `<p>` can have `id="word"` in valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use `class="text word"`, because the HTML id attribute is used to specify a unique id for an HTML element. You cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document.

**JS**:

```js
var wordsArray = ["Andre", "Anne", "Billy", "Clark","David", "Edward", "Gee", "Jasper", "Kelvin", "Steven", "Tom", "Willy"]; 
    
var t = setInterval(function() { 
var words = document.querySelectorAll('.word')
words.forEach((word) => {
var randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * (wordsArray.length-1) ); 
  console.log(randomNumber)
  word.innerText = wordsArray[randomNumber] }); 
}, 5000)
```

```css
.word {
align-content: center;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src=".../word.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="word">Franco</p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="word">Henry</p>
</div>
</body>
```

var wordsArray = ["Andre", "Anne", "Billy", "Clark","David", "Edward", "Gee", "Jasper", "Kelvin", "Steven", "Tom", "Willy"];

```
var t = setInterval(function() { 
var words = document.querySelectorAll('.word')
words.forEach((word) => {
  var randomNumber = Math.round( Math.random() * (words.length-1) ); 
  word.html( words[randomNumber] ); }, 5000); 
})
```

**HTML**:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../word.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="word">Franco</p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="word">Henry</p>//in this class the javascript doesn't work
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```
.word {
align-content: center;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: I already trying this sir, but its still doesn't work sir. Maybe because p call 2 class. in this class "text" means css sir.

Comment: Try this code. Hit the Run Code Snippet button and see.

Answer (score 0):

An ID must be unique in a document.

By adding your script twice, you have two scripts which **at the same time** modify the *first element with the ID they search for*.

One will overwrite the results of the other before you can notice the change.

---

If you want to have the script affect two different elements then there are a couple of approaches you can take:

You could use a **class** instead of an ID and then have your function loop over the elements with that class and update each one.

You could use **different IDs** and change your code so it accepts the ID to modify as an argument instead of hard coding it. Then you can call that function twice.

Comment: can you please show me The example sir?

Comment: I already try to make word1.js until word11.js but its still doesn't work when i called in tag p as <p class="text" id=word1.js">